# how to read nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

i have a json data which is complex nested array.which is something like this

```
   Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [description] => description
        [arrayGroup] => Array
            (
                [owner] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => owner
                        [apiListings] => Array
                            (
                                [product_number1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [availableVersions] => Array
                                            (
                                                [v1.1.0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [resourceName] => Product name

                                                    )

                                                [v0.1.0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                       [resourceName] => Product name

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [apiName] => product_number1
                                    )
                                     [product_number1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [availableVersions] => Array
                                            (
                                                [v1.1.0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [resourceName] => Product name

                                                    )

                                                [v0.1.0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                       [resourceName] => Product name

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [apiName] => product_number1
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
    )
```

For this array i want the data of [resourceName] for [v1.1.0]  and the [apiName]
How can i do so in php ? please help me with this tyvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you assign your array of nested arrays like this:

```
$object = array(...); //your array made from JSON data
```

So now, to get the information you want for product1, you have to select it from arrays respecting the order (so you give the text indices of more and more nested arrays):

```
$resourceNameProduct1 = $object['arrayGroup']['owner']['apiListings']['product_number1']['availableVersions']['v1.1.0']['resourceName'];
$apiNameProduct1 = $object['arrayGroup']['owner']['apiListings']['product_number1']['apiName'];
```

For example, for `$resourceNameProduct1` you go from `$object` array to `$object['arrayGroup']` (first `[...]`) than to $object['arrayGroup']['owner']`(second`[...]`) etc.

Once you are  "inside" of sub-array, e.g. `$object['arrayGroup']['owner']` you can forget about the whole `$object` and focus on what is left under object > arrayGroup > owner.

**Side note:** If you would deal with object with properties instead of an array, you could do the same with a bit different selector:

```
$resourceNameProduct1 = $object.arrayGroup.owner.apiListings.product_number1.availableVersions.{'v1.1.0'}.resourceName;
```

Note the `{'...'}` here for `v1.1.0` - it's because that string contains dots and you want to make it clear that you request the `v1.1.0` property and not `0` property of `1` of `v1`.

Comment: tyvm for the help :). it really helped me a lot.

Comment: @Racoon glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$resourceName = $variable['arrayGroup']['owner']['apiListings']['product_number1']['availableVersions']['v1.1.0']['resourceName'];
$apiName = $variable['arrayGroup']['owner']['apiListings']['product_number1'][apiName'];
```

Comment: Sorry, duplicated.

Comment: ty its the same but ty for the effort :)